# How to patten match on a field of a state monad?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, state-monad, pattern-guards

Is it possible to write write the function `a` using pattens matching/guards?

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternGuards #-}
import Control.Monad.State.Strict(State, gets, runStateT)
data MyState = MyState
    { counter :: Int
    } deriving (Show)


a :: State MyState String
a = do
    i <- gets counter
    case i of
        0 -> return "hello"
        1 -> return "bye"

run = runStateT a ( MyState{counter=0} )
```

I tried writing `a` as

```
a' :: State MyState String
a' | i <- gets counter, i == 0 = return "hello"
```

but got the errors:

```
No instance for (Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState MyState m0)
  arising from a use of ‘gets’
The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState s m =>
           Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState
             s (Control.Monad.Trans.Cont.ContT r m)
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.State.Class’
  instance (Control.Monad.Trans.Error.Error e,
            Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState s m) =>
           Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState
             s (Control.Monad.Trans.Error.ErrorT e m)
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.State.Class’
  instance Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState s m =>
           Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState
             s (Control.Monad.Trans.Except.ExceptT e m)
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.State.Class’
  ...plus 12 others
In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               an equation for ‘a'’:
  i <- gets counter
In an equation for ‘a'’:
    a' | i <- gets counter, i == 0 = return "hello"

No instance for (Eq (m0 Int)) arising from a use of ‘==’
The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  i :: m0 Int (bound at src/TestGen/Arbitrary/Helpers/Z.hs:18:6)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Eq a => Eq (GHC.Real.Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
  instance (Eq e, Data.Functor.Classes.Eq1 m, Eq a) =>
           Eq (Control.Monad.Trans.Error.ErrorT e m a)
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Error’
  ...plus 118 others
In the expression: i == 0
In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               an equation for ‘a'’:
  i == 0
In an equation for ‘a'’:
    a' | i <- gets counter, i == 0 = return "hello"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible. Left arrow in the pattern guard syntax is *mostly* unrelated to the left arrow in the do-notation.

You can use the new lambda-case extension if you like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
a :: State MyState String
a = gets counter >>= \case
        0 -> return "hello"
        1 -> return "bye"
```

Or multi-way if, perhaps?

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}
a :: State MyState String
a = do
    i <- gets counter
    if
      | i == 0 -> return "hello"
      | i == 1 -> return "bye"
```

Comment: LambdaCase is quite nice for this.

Comment: Since all branches begin with `return` you can rewrite it with `(<&>) = flip fmap` as: `gets counter <&> \case 0 -> "hello"; 1 -> "bye"`. `(<&>)` is from the lens package https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13.2.1/docs/Control-Lens-Operators.html#v:-60--38--62-

Answer (score 3):

No. There are some really fundamental conceptual mismatches here.

**Pattern matching** only works when the topmost part of the expression is a *constructor* function, but the head of a `do`-style block is going to be a *normal function* (in this case the function `>>=` defined in the typeclasss `Monad`).

**Guards** expect a value of type `Bool` but the value you're going to hand them will have to be of type `State MyState Bool` (since one of the distinctive things about monads is that you cannot escape from them). So guards will also never work.

You **can** however reach for the **functor instance**. Functors are defined in the Prelude; there is an infix form of `fmap` called `<$>` in `Control.Applicative`. You would use this by saying:

```
a' = process <$> gets counter
    where 
        process 0 = "hello"
        process _ = "bye"
```

or doing whatever you want with the `process` function. To get something more like `>>=` you could also define your own operator as `flip fmap` and then you can write, say, `gets counter >= \x -> case x of ...`.

Comment: Pattern guards (standard since Haskell 2010) are more powerful than ordinary guards, and don't need to be `Bool`s. They're not powerful enough for this use case, however.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write a helper?

```
pureA :: MyState -> String
pureA (MyState 0) = "hello"
pureA (MyState 1) = "bye"
pureA _           = ""

a :: State MyState String
a = fmap doA get
```

This also follows the philosophy of separating concerns of pure logic from your impure logic.

Comment: How is `State` monad impure?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this *is* possible, but I would advise you not to do it—it's hard to keep track of which piece goes where.

```
import Control.Monad.State.Strict(StateT(..))
import Data.Functor.Identity(Identity(..))

data MyState = MyState
    { counter :: Int
    } deriving (Show)

a :: StateT MyState Identity String
a = StateT $ \ s@(MyState i) -> Identity $
  case i of
    0 -> ("hello", s)
    1 -> ("bye", s)
```